# Collecting baggage when transiting & quarantine rules

Tags: uk, transit, covid-19, quarantine, finnish-citizens

I'm arriving to the London Gatwick Airport to change plane when returning from Canary Islands. However, I will be self connecting the flights so I will need to pick up the luggage myself, and then check-in again. As Spain (Canary Islands included) is removed from Border Rules exempt list, and travelers are subject to 14-day quarantine, will this affect my second flight from Gatwick?

[UK COVID-19 Travel guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/coronavirus-covid-19-travellers-exempt-from-uk-border-rules/coronavirus-covid-19-travellers-exempt-from-uk-border-rules#people-transiting-airside-individuals-who-arrive-in-the-uk-but-do-not-pass-border-control) states that people transiting airside are exempt from border rules, but as I have to collect the baggage, I think I will need to pass the Border Control. Can I just check-in normally and proceed to my next flight?

I'm travelling to Finland and I'm finnish myself

Comment: There is a "Gatwick Connects Baggage Service" which I've never used. I'm not sure if it requires you to pass immigration control. Perhaps somebody here has experience with it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.